# Partial Differentiation of the Mass Matrix for Free-Floating system with 7 DoF Arm

Tags: drake

I'm trying to partially differentiate the mass matrix with respect to the positions (including the free-floating base quaternions). However, I try to first substitute the unit quaternion constraint in the symbolic mass matrix i.e. [image: unit quaternion constraint]  and then differentiate with respect to all the positions (except q_0).

When I try to use `plant.ToSymbolic()` and then extract the symbolic mass matrix using `plant.CalcMassMatrixViaInverseDynamics()` (`ManipulatorDynamics` function taken from [this example](https://github.com/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/0e2fa1858067a260a9c71d2b4d122561e11383d6/underactuated/multibody.py)) it works for a single free-floating rigid body (3-DoF floating) and also for a free-floating box with a 3-DoF arm (6-DoF system) but the same process does not work when I change to a 7-DoF arm attached to the floating base (13-DoF system). The mass matrix is computed but the function to substitute the unit quaternion constraint takes too long (never finishes and returns). Portion of the applicable code:

```py
q0 = Variable("q0")
q1 = Variable("q1")
q2 = Variable("q2")
q3 = Variable("q3")

unit_cons = Expression.sqrt(1 - q1**2 - q2**2 - q3**2)

mixed_q = np.array([q0, q1, q2, q3,
                    0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
v = np.zeros(plant.num_velocities())

(M, Cv, tauG, B, tauExt) = ManipulatorDynamics(plant.ToSymbolic(), mixed_q, v)
M[0, 0].Substitute({q0: unit_cons})
```

This runs well for a single floating rigid body, floating body + 3-DoF arm. But the last line takes a long time and never returns for a floating base + 7-DoF arm.

Is there a better way to approach this with Drake's symbolic engine? Or would AutoDiff be a better choice for this? I only need the 1st partial derivative in this case.

As for some background, I am trying to create a custom linearization of the MultiBodyPlant which embeds the unit quaternion constraint. This requires the partial derivatives of the terms **after** substituting the unit quaternion constraint to only have the vector part of the quaternion in the equations of motion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or would AutoDiff be a better choice for this? I only need the 1st partial derivative in this case.

If you want to evaluate the partial differentiation, then I would suggest using autodiff. To handle your unit quaternion constraint, you can compute your q0 from the vector part of the quaternion.

Here is the pseudo code.

```py
quaternion_vec_val = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
q_non_quaternion_val = np.array([0.4, 0.5, 0.6])
q_variable = np.concantenate((quaternion_vec_val, q_non_quaternion_val))
# We want to take derivative w.r.t the vector part of the quaternion, and all non-quaternion variables. Hence we call InitializeAutoDiff on the variables we want to take derivative.
q_variable_ad = pydrake.math.Initialize(q_variable)
quaternion_scalar_ad = np.array([np.sqrt(1 - np.sum(q_variable_ad[:3]**2))])
q_ad = np.concantenate((quaternion_scalar_ad, q_variable_ad))
plant_ad = plant.ToAutoDiffXd()
# Initialize v_ad
v_ad = np.zeros(6, dtype=np.object)
for i in range(6):
  v_ad[i] = pydrake.AutoDiffXd(0)
(M, C, g, B, tau_ext) = ManipulatorDynamics(plant_ad, q_ad, v_ad)
print(M(0, 0).derivatives())
```

(I haven't run the code, especially the part that initializes v_ad is fuzzy, but hopefully you get the idea).